# How to Search Elements by Title in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script

I am trying to create some scripts that click on elements in a Chrome web page, using the console. At first I was doing it by "Name":
`document.getElementsByName("name")[0].click()`
but then I realized that the name of the button changes every instance of the page. The button also doesn't have an ID. So the next most specific attribute I could find is the Title. Is there something similar to the above code I can use to like `getElementByTitle`?

Also, the button I want to click has Title "Save Changes", however there is always a button before it with Title "Save Changes ad close". Will it click that one first?

Comment: You might need to add a class name to all the buttons that you want to click, then use `getElementsByClassName()`  You may also need to save the element that is currently displayed, and restrict the search to that element.  For example, if you have tabs, put the id of the current tab into the window.  That would be part of your navigation system if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
document.querySelector("[title='Save Changes']")
```

This will get you the first element that has the attribute `title` set to `Save Changes`.

You can learn more about the CSS attribute selector from [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)